# Trying to make a Camera app, new to Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

This is the ViewController file. I'm following the tutorial here:
https://www.appcoda.com/avfoundation-swift-guide/

I don't understand the errors:

"Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[AVCaptureDevice]'"

and

"Value of optional type 'AVCapturePhotoOutput?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"

What do these errors mean? How can I fix them?

```
  //
//  CameraController.swift
//  AV Foundation
//
//  Created by ben on 5/10/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Pranjal Satija. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import UIKit
class CameraController {
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?

    var currentCameraPosition: CameraPosition?

    var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var frontCameraInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?

    var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?

    var rearCamera: AVCaptureDevice?
    var rearCameraInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
}

extension CameraController {
    func displayPreview(on view: UIView) throws {
        guard let captureSession = self.captureSession, captureSession.isRunning else { throw CameraControllerError.captureSessionIsMissing }

        self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        self.previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
        self.previewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait

        view.layer.insertSublayer(self.previewLayer!, at: 0)
        self.previewLayer?.frame = view.frame
    }

    func prepare(completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        func createCaptureSession() {
            self.captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        }

        func configureCaptureDevices() throws {
            let session = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .unspecified)
            guard let cameras = (session.devices.flatMap { $0 }), !cameras.isEmpty else { throw CameraControllerError.noCamerasAvailable }

            for camera in cameras {
                if camera.position == .front {
                    self.frontCamera = camera
                }

                if camera.position == .back {
                    self.rearCamera = camera

                    try camera.lockForConfiguration()
                    camera.focusMode = .autoFocus
                    camera.unlockForConfiguration()
                }
            }
        }

        func configureDeviceInputs() throws {
            guard let captureSession = self.captureSession else { throw CameraControllerError.captureSessionIsMissing }

            if let rearCamera = self.rearCamera {
                self.rearCameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: rearCamera)

                if captureSession.canAddInput(self.rearCameraInput!) { captureSession.addInput(self.rearCameraInput!) }

                self.currentCameraPosition = .rear
            }

            else if let frontCamera = self.frontCamera {
                self.frontCameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: frontCamera)

                if captureSession.canAddInput(self.frontCameraInput!) { captureSession.addInput(self.frontCameraInput!) }
                else { throw CameraControllerError.inputsAreInvalid }

                self.currentCameraPosition = .front
            }

            else { throw CameraControllerError.noCamerasAvailable }
        }

        func configurePhotoOutput() throws {
            guard let captureSession = self.captureSession else { throw CameraControllerError.captureSessionIsMissing }

            self.photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
            self.photoOutput!.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG])], completionHandler: nil)

            if captureSession.canAddOutput(self.photoOutput) { captureSession.addOutput(self.photoOutput) }
            captureSession.startRunning()
        }

        DispatchQueue(label: "prepare").async {
            do {
                createCaptureSession()
                try configureCaptureDevices()
                try configureDeviceInputs()
                try configurePhotoOutput()
            }

            catch {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completionHandler(error)
                }

                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completionHandler(nil)
            }
        }
    }
}

extension CameraController {
    enum CameraControllerError: Swift.Error {
        case captureSessionAlreadyRunning
        case captureSessionIsMissing
        case inputsAreInvalid
        case invalidOperation
        case noCamerasAvailable
        case unknown
    }

    public enum CameraPosition {
        case front
        case rear
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read through the [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) section of the Swift book.

Comment: I don't understand Swift well enough to understand the Swift book. Can you direct me to the relevant line that would help me make changes? Why did the code work for the AppCoda OP but doesn't anymore?

Comment: The whole of the Swift book is to understand/learn Swift. Perhaps you should start with the first page and go from there. You need to learn the language. Copying and pasting existing code is useful to practice what you learn but you really need to take the time to learn the language. Read the book. It will save you a lot of time in the long run.

Comment: As @rmaddy said you really should read more about Swift and coding in general. It’s pointless to copy and paste large sections of code without understanding it. To resolve your problem immediately you can probably just hit the fix button in the error which will correct the issue for you. An over simplified explanation of why you need ! or ? is because the program doesn’t know if the value will be nil (empty) and so it needs to know how to treat it. If you use ! it will assume it will never be nil but if it is your app will crash. If you use ? the value will be optional and so can be nil...

Comment: I understand that. I was able to resolve that second error upon researching optionals. However, this line

Comment: guard let cameras = (session.devices.flatMap { $0 }), !cameras.isEmpty else { throw CameraControllerError.noCamerasAvailable } throws a "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[AVCaptureDevice]'" error. I don't see anywhere in the Swift book that tells me what this error means.

Answer (score 3):

In one of your comments you finally pointed out which line is causing an error:

```
guard let cameras = (session.devices.flatMap { $0 }), !cameras.isEmpty else { throw CameraControllerError.noCamerasAvailable }
```

There are several issues with this. As you can find in the [Control Flow - Early Exit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID120) section of the Swift book, `guard let` is used to verify that an optional variable isn't `nil`.

The error is telling you that the expression `(session.devices.flatMap { $0 })` isn't an optional. In fact, the use of `flatMap` here is pointless since `session.devices` is an array of non-optional values (`[AVCaptureDevice]]`).

You should rewrite the `guard` to:

```
guard !session.devices.isEmpty else {
    throw CameraControllerError.noCamerasAvailable
}
```

And then the loop becomes:

```
for camera in session.devices {
```